# Https android to server communication always returns 403 response

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I am stuck with this for past two days where i have to implement mutual authentication to the server with client certificate. I have my .pfx file inside raw folder in res directory.

I have it in res/raw/certificate.pfx

I have also implemented the HttpUrlConnection in android and set the SSLSocketFactory to the one which i generated from my certificate. But the problem is the server always returns 403. I have tried adding all request property including "User Agent". But nothing seems to be working.

I have attached the code below. I am trusting the certificate like this.

```
public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory_Certificate(String keyStoreType, int keystoreResId)
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchProviderException {

    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(keystoreResId);

    // creating a KeyStore containing trusted CAs

    if (keyStoreType == null || keyStoreType.length() == 0) {
        keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    }
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

    keyStore.load(caInput, "".toCharArray());

    // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in the KeyStore

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);

    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

And finally in my activity i make https call as follows

```
URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://example.com");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            }
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Server response code" + responseCode);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But the outcome is always 403 forbidden. I am not sure where i am going wrong. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah.. Finally i found the issue myself. All i was missing is i failed to initialize my keystore factory with the keystore after i loaded the certificate.

```
public SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory_Certificate(String keyStoreType, int keystoreResId)
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchProviderException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(keystoreResId);

    // creating a KeyStore containing trusted CAs

    if (keyStoreType == null || keyStoreType.length() == 0) {
        keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    }
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(caInput, "".toCharArray());

    // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in the KeyStore

    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, "".toCharArray());

    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), wrappedTrustManagers, null);
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

These lines made the trick for me.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, "".toCharArray());

    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), wrappedTrustManagers, null);
```

Hope it would help someone. :)